# How to make a postgreSQL image postGIS enabled using Docker Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I followed the following steps to make my a custom image of postgresql database:

```
docker pull postgresql
```

Then

```
makdir postgresql
touch Dockerfile
sudo nano Dockerfile
```

Edited the docker file to be like below:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER tenali<tenali@yahoo.com>
RUN apt-get update
RUN docker pull mdillon/postgis
```

now when i do

```
sudo docker build -t gautam/postgresql:v2 .
```

I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: docker: not found
```

I guess what that's saying is the command docker does't exist in /bin/sh , i guess i am making a mistake in writing the Dockerfile. can you check my Dockerfile and tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: So first, you don't need to run `sudo` to edit your Dockerfile (in fact, that will likely come back to bite you at some point), and secondly "`docker`: not found` suggets that you simply do not have docker installed at this time.  It has nothing to do with the contents of your Dockerfile.

Comment: @larsks , if i run docker from the terminal , instead of writing a dockerfile , it runs fine

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the formatting of your post meant that  I didn't notice your Dockerfile.  I fixed that for you.  You would not run `docker pull` inside a Dockerfile.  What you probably want is something like:

```
FROM mdillon/postgis
MAINTAINER tenali<tenali@yahoo.com>
RUN apt-get update
```

The `FROM` directive means, effectively, "pull this image if it doesn't already exist and use it as the base for the image I am creating with this Dockerfile".

It's not clear from your question what the relationship is between the `postgresql` image and the `mdillon/postgis` image, or why you're pulling one then using the other.

Comment: i need my postgreSQL database to be postGIS enabled !! thats why i am pulling mdillon/postgis .. do you think i am going in the right direction as far as enableing my postgresql database is concerned(as i said i need to make it postGIS enabled) ?

Comment: According to [the description](https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/), `mdillon/postgis` already *is* a postgis-enabled PostgreSQL installation.

Comment: ! Danm ! missed that , ok how do i make a postgreSQL database image , postGIS enabled , i need to do this using dockerfile and i can't use `mdillon/postgis` ... sorry for the confusion